# Showing image in gridpsec by `ax.imshow` causes image to lose its alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-sheets

```
a, b = 10, 10
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))

gs = fig.add_gridspec(4, 4)
axes1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 0:2])
axes2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 0:2])
axes3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4, 2:4])


axes1.scatter(np.random.randn(3), np.random.randn(3))
axes2.scatter(np.random.randn(3), np.random.randn(3), c="g")
axes3.scatter(np.random.randn(3), np.random.randn(3), c="r")
axes3.imshow(img)

axes1.set_title("1", y=1, pad=-11)
axes2.set_title("2", y=1, pad=-11)
axes3.set_title("3", y=1, pad=-11)
axes1.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axes1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axes2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes3.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes3.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

  
fig.tight_layout(pad=-1)
plt.show()
```

The code above produces the image below:

Non-aligned image:

[image]

However, the third image should fill the all available space on the right. If I comment the

```
axes3.imshow(img)
```

code, the alignment becomes corrected. And the image produced is

Aligned image:

[image]

Appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

I have tried to play with image size but it did not help.

Comment: What is the shape of your image?

Comment: imshow respects the aspect of the image, you cannot fit a square pef in a rectangular hole.

Comment: @gboffi Yeah. that was the problem. I needed to change the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: @jared That was a square image. After changing the aspect ratio to be the same with the gridspec's, it fitted.

Comment: If it's really an image, if you change its shape you are going to deform it, maybe you can try to cut a tall&short portion of it...

Comment: Yeah you are right, it deformed it. Actually, i decided to overlay the other two on the image. Like picture-in-picture.